# "Pulling back a function from a neighborhood of 0 in $\mathbb{C}^2$ to $\mathbb{U}$ is analogous to computing the derivative of that function."

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces

I'm reading on Riemann Surfaces and after defining 
$$\mathbb{U} \equiv \{(z,\ell)\in\mathbb{C}^2\times\mathbb{P}_1;z\in\ell\},$$ and 
$B\ell_0:\mathbb{U}\to\mathbb{C}^2$, the author mentions that, "Pulling back a function from a neighborhood of 0 in $\mathbb{C}^2$ to $\mathbb{U}$ is analogous to computing the derivative of that function."

I understand what $\mathbb{P}_1$ is but I'm not 100% on the analogy. Is there an intuitive way to understand this?

Comment: oh I see, blow up at 0?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. $B\ell_0$ is the blowup of 0 in $\mathbb{C}^2$.

Comment: what is the book you're reading?

Comment: _Riemann Surfaces by Way of Complex Analytic Geometry_ by Varolin

Comment: Well the blowup at a point can be thought of replacing that point with a copy of $\mathbb{P}^1$, where the copy of $\mathbb{P}^1$ can be thought of all the possible tangent lines at that point, and of course tangent lines and derivatives are pretty connected...

Comment: I really cannot find such a statement in the book you mentioned and it really sounds strange to me ... the pullback of a function will be the same exact function, just constantly equal to $f(0)$ on the exceptional divisor (i.e. $B\ell_0^{–1}(0,0)\cong \mathbb{P}^1$).

Comment: It's stated on page 28, in Statement (1).

Comment: Funny enough, in this version (http://mathnt.mat.jhu.edu/zelditch/Teaching/F09RS/DrorRS.pdf ) statement 1 ends just before the line you mention (p. 39)